# 1st time not getting response from the sever android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Code in java class:

```
public String POST(String url, final Map<String, String> params, final VolleyCallBack callBack) {

        //RequestFuture<String> requestFuture = new RequestFuture.newFuture();
        RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            val = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            callBack.onSuccess();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                ToastMsg(error.getMessage() + " " + error.getStackTrace()[0]);
            }
        }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return params;
            }
        };

        RetryPolicy mRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


        return val;
    }
```

**Code in Activity Class:**

```
val = db.POST(Constants.URL_FacultyLogin, map);
```

For the 1st time when I click on the button I'm not getting a response from the server but 2nd I'm getting a response can anyone help me out why not for the 1st time.

Comment: Another victim of asynchronous call . `StringRequest` is an  asynchronous  call and you just returned a null val cause its modifying inside `onResponse`.

Comment: Then what is better way to call from sever?

Comment: I see you are already using a callback like `callBack.onSuccess();`. So you do not need to return from method Just provide a callback method in both cases success and failure .

Comment: if write the same code in activity class means I'm getting a response for the 1st time but why it is not working from java class file to activity class

Comment: The reason its not working for first time is maybe you have declared `val` as global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use asynctask [Refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Call your volley function here
        }



@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        //The result variable holds your val returned from volley 
       }
```

Comment: if write the same code in activity class means I'm getting a response for the 1st time but why it is not working from java class file to activity class

Comment: Not getting response from the server on first-time click of a button but 2nd click on button im getting response so that is my issue

Comment: This is because volley uses worker thread and the response takes time and before response is returned your method is returning string which is null.